# TextTrimming not working

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7.1.1

I have data binding to a listbox, and texttrimming property set to WordEllipsis, but it doesn't seem to work. The textblocks are showing text as if they do without the texttrimming property set. This is my xaml code. Please help.

```
           <Grid>
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <application:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <TextBlock Height="75" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Click on Settings to search for quotes (by author or by query)." VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="26.667"/>
                <ListBox Margin="0,166,0,0" Name="lstQuote" DoubleTap="lstQuote_DoubleTap" Hold="lstQuote_Hold">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <es:RegularPolygon Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="90" InnerRadius="0.47211" PointCount="5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="84"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quote}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontSize="30" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Width="Auto" />

                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                <Button Content="Random Quote" Height="79" Margin="48,83,44,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="quotSearch" Click="quotSearch_Click" />
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change TextBox Width properties to fixed width

```
<TextBlock Width="200" Height="75" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Click on Settings to search for quotes (by author or by query)." VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="26.667"/>
```

Comment: I think you have mistaken the textblock. The textblock that I intended to point out is the TextBlock inside the stackpanel which has data binding.